# Can you add a modal background to a Kendo window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-window

Using **kendo ui**,   and using the **window** UI WIDGET, http://demos.kendoui.com/web/window/index.html

Is it possible to add a modal background in light grey color like you can in Jquery ui dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal ?

Is it possible to make the background non-clickable ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply use the [`modal`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window#configuration-modal) configuration option:

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    modal: true
});
```

You can adjust the color by overriding the CSS if necessary.

Comment: Didn't see this in the demos of the KendoUI website, glad it is implemented and this simple :)